# Next Previous buttons with AVPlayerViewController and AVQueuePlayer not working

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm using an `AVPlayerViewController` to play a number of videos, via `AVQueuePlayer`. The problem is that the previous/next buttons don't seem to do anything. I can't find any way of being notified when those buttons are touched. Am I missing something?

The code I'm using is pretty simple:

```
self.player = AVQueuePlayer(items: playerItems)
self.playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
self.playerViewController?.player = self.player
self.presentViewController(self.playerViewController!, animated: false, completion: { () -> Void in
    self.playerViewController?.player.play()
})
```

Comment: Having this same issue. Did you ever figure out what was going on?

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I think I read something about the arrows being used for chapter markers. Could be wrong though. Will post a link if I find where I saw that.

Comment: Found it. Look at the 2014 WWDC video entitled Mastering Modern Media Playback. They don't go into detail about it but it list chapter navigation as one of the features. So my best bet is that's what it's for. I suppose you could add a chapter right at the end and somehow hook it to that but seems like it's going against how they'd have you to do it.

Comment: Thanks for following up, I guess that must be the reason. Bit of a shame though, seems like something worth filing a RADAR about.

Comment: Well the movie said that MPMoviePlayerController did it that same way so they probably don't want to make it suddenly do something different. That is one of the main things they push with the new AVPlayerViewController is that it gives a common UI that the user will be familiar with. The main thing that would be nice is being able to hide them if you don't have chapters as it is a little confusing why the buttons don't work. Regardless I'll live with it.

Comment: One other note, while it might not be what you want, you might be able to use the contentOverlayView to put in some custom controls. Apple's docs: Applications can use the content overlay view to add additional custom views between the video content and the controls. You'd just need to lay it out to be above the controls to not get blocked. I have a feeling this might be more for bugs, logos, watermarks or things like that and haven't tested to see if disappears when the controls disappear but I think that's your best bet short of doing a custom UI with AVPlayer

Comment: That's a decent idea. I ended up solving my problem by creating a custom UI, which actually wasn't too much work. In hindsight though, if I'd know I would have given the custom overlay a try first.

Comment: @BrianFLeighty from my experience the contentOverlayView is not user interaction enabled and you can't do anything about that.